# Stop GridView header scrolling

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Here is my ASPX code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="xyz.aspx.cs" Inherits="xyz" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div style=" font-size:x-small; overflow:auto; width:660px; height:180px; ">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SR No"><ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="test_1" HeaderText="First No" SortExpression="test_1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="test_2" HeaderText="Second No" SortExpression="test_2" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:paconn %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [c_test] ORDER BY [test_1]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

I want that my GridView header fixed on their position and the other data are scrolled on vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some hundreds of hours on this. The answer, I have decided is two gridviews. One for the header and one below, in a scrollable div, for the data. Use the same styling for each.  Establish the size of the screen and set the div to a fixed height and width and set the gridviews to be 20px narrower than the div. On the PreRender event of one of the gridviews, set the column widths of both gridviews to be identical. At last I have perfectly sized gridviews that fill the page (or appear where I want them) with a static header and perfectly aligned columns. You can add controls in the gridview header columns that you can use to do sorting etc.